# Rails way to check for object existence before display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to find a nice way to check my objects before i display them in the view so I wont get errors.

This is my controler

```
 @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
 @profile = @user.profile 
 @questions = @user.questions
```

and this is my view

```
 <% unless @profile.blank? %><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', :controller => 'profiles', :action => 'edit' %><% end %>


     <% unless @user.blank? %>
        Username:<%= @user.username %><br />
    Member Since:<%= @user.created_at.strftime("%d %B %Y")  %><br />
    <% end %>

  <% unless @profile.blank? %>
    First Name: <%= @profile.first_name %><br />
    Last Name: <%= @profile.last_name %><br /><br />
    About: <%= @profile.body %><br /><br />
    Location: <%= @profile.location %><br />
    Birthday: <%= @profile.birthday.strftime("%d %B %Y") %><br />
    <% end %>
```

As you can see, I'm using more than one checking of each kind ( check unless @profile.blank? ) and I think there will be a better way to do that.

Is there any Rails way to do something smarter than the one I've come up with ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I see, there is no way you can skip this @.blank? validation as you dont want to display the records if they are empty but I have few suggestions

1 - Make  following sections as partials

```
<% unless @user.blank? %>
    Username:<%= @user.username %><br />
    Member Since:<%= @user.created_at.strftime("%d %B %Y")  %><br />
<% end %>
```

and

```
<% unless @profile.blank? %>
  First Name: <%= @profile.first_name %><br />
  Last Name: <%= @profile.last_name %><br /><br />
  About: <%= @profile.body %><br /><br />
  Location: <%= @profile.location %><br />
  Birthday: <%= @profile.birthday.strftime("%d %B %Y") %><br />
<% end %>
```

it will keep your view cleaner and will give you the flexibility of using them in anyware in your app

2 - take the below line

```
<% unless @profile.blank? %><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', :controller => 'profiles', :action=> 'edit' %><% end %>
```

inside the profile display as its more appropriate

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 10):

Also

```
<%= if @object.present? %>
```

looks much simplier for me than

```
<%= unless @object.blank? %>
```

especially when we have more than one conditional statement (`&&` \ `||` \ `and` \ `or`).

[api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)

Answer (score 1):

According to the rails documentation, you can see if any associated objects exist by using the association.nil? method:

```
if @book.author.nil?
  @msg = "No author found for this book"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about building empty profile for user before saving it? How about using analogy with exclamation mark which will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` which in turn will display 404 page.

P.S. I'd also recommend trimming controller down to one instance variable.

Comment: I just dont want to display the users info ( profile etc ) if the user doesnt have one. How an empty profile would help me to do that ?

Comment: ok then - what's the point of creating a user without a profile?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the rails approach would be to use [Object#presence](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence)

you should always `unless @object.blank?` as you did.